# How can i find how many times a letter appears if there are only 8 positions?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

[image]

I'm having trouble with this question.

a appears in the first position 50388 times

b appears in the first position 31824 times and in the second 18564 times etc,

so in order to calculate a

i did $19C7$

for b: it  was $18C7$ for the first position and $18C6$ for the second

for c I did $17C7$ and got 19448 but $17C6$ or $17C5$ didn't work

What am I doing wrong?

I know all the letters appear 50388 times but how can i explain this without adding each individual total

i think if i understand part a then i can do part b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your set of words is all the ${20 \choose 8}=125\ 970$ words by taking $8$ letters out of the $20$ without replacement and keeping the letters in alphabetical order.  $a$ always appears in first position if it is present because nothing else comes before.  $b$ appears first if $a$ is not present, so you need to choose $7$ letters out of the remaining $18$ to complete the word.  If $a$ and $b$ are both present, you have to choose $6$ out of the remaining $18$ to complete the word.  For $c$, if it is in first position $a$ and $b$ are missing, so you need to choose $7$ of the remaining $17$ letters to complete the word.  If it is in second position, exactly one of $a$ or $b$ is present.

Comment: how can i calculate the number for if c was in the second position? it would be 17C7 + something? im still confused about what i need to use in order to solve the problem

Comment: how many ways to choose the letter before it?  how many ways to choose the letters after?

Comment: for the choosing the letter before it, there are two choices and 7 positions so 7C2?

Comment: No, there is only one position before it.  Because the letters are kept in order in the word you never select positions, you just select letters and the positions are set.

Comment: so wouldn't it be 2C1 since there are two letters that could be there but only one letter that fits?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: or 20C2? im not sure why it would be 20 c2 though

Comment: but 2C1 is just 2

Comment: oh so it would be 2c1 * 17c6 ?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: thank you! so then for letter d, first position would be 16C7, second would 3C1*16C6 and third would be be 3C1*2C1*16C5?

Comment: No, it is not. You can check the given number to see that is wrong.

Comment: but why? for the second position i got the correct answer. but for the third position it would be that first position has 3 letters to choose from so 3c1, second position has 2 letters remaining to choose from so 2c1, then the third would just be 16c5

Comment: No, you just choose two of the three letters to come before $d$.  Your computation allows $b$ to be first and $a$ to be second.

Comment: thanks for the help!